# Hide div refresh while using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I use setInterval to update a table every 5 seconds which works great except that it creates a "**blinking**" effect since the Div refreshes as if I pressed <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Is it possible to hide it with example `fadeIn()` function? I have tried but without any luck so far. Does anyone have any experience with this?

```js
var append_increment = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  $("#_change tr").remove();
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "{% url 'tables' %}",
      data: {
        ' tables ': append_increment
      }
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      $('#_change').append(response).fadeIn("milliseconds", "linear");

      append_increment += 0;
    });
}, 5000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flickering happen because you update the content before the ajax call completes not after it

you can  try this

```
var append_increment = 0;
var Di = setInterval("clearInterval(Di);GetData();", 5000);
        function GetData(){
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url 'tables' %}",
            data: {' tables ': append_increment}
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            $('#_change tr').html(response).fadeIn(500, "linear");
            Di=setInterval("clearInterval(Di);GetData();",5000);
            append_increment += 0;
        });
}
```

2. Also let the html response from server be without `<tr></tr>`

Comment: Hi Rkv88, I tried both of the solutions but cant quite get them to work. The first solutions removes all data after 5 seconds. The second solution still blinks unfortunately.

Comment: for the second solution  , try sending data without <tr>

Comment: check answer i edited the code  , also pls add html table to get clear picture

Comment: This one solved it it seems, i removed the tr from $('#_change tr') in order to avoid duplicates, think it works great now. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you use two setInterval? :-)

Comment: it just restarts the interval  so it will only create another interval only after we get data from server .

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is make all the changes in memory before issuing a DOM refresh (an expensive process).  This can be done with the `detach()` event:

```js
var append_increment = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "{% url 'tables' %}",
      data: {
        ' tables ': append_increment
      }
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      let $table = $('#_change')
      let $parent = $table.parent()
      $table.detatch()
      $table.find('tr').remove();
      $table.append(response);
      $parent.append($table);

      append_increment += 0;
    });
}, 5000)
```

More than likely, it wouldn't solve flickering.  For that, a closer example would need to be given.  Some of that could be the amount of painting to the screen, some might be the delay of the AJAX.  You are removing and creating elements, so a "flicker" is expected -- this is also where a library like React, which uses a virtual DOM, would excel.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be some flicker (most of the time negligible) when content is updated. A way to reduce this even more is to have two tables and as soon as the background table is filled, then swap it to the front and continue exchanging the two views, but is probably unnecessary.

To minimize the flicker time in this case, I would suggest to move the .remove() function into the .done() in the line right before the .append(). Even though code acts fast, sometimes our eyes can see small delays.

This solution should make sure that the data is not being removed until the AJAX call has completed a return. I would also go one step further and check the response to make sure the call returned successfully just for robustness.

```js
var append_increment = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "{% url 'tables' %}",
      data: {
        ' tables ': append_increment
      }
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      if (/* response['statusCode'] == 200 */) {
        $("#_change tr").remove();
        $('#_change').append(response);
        append_increment += 0;
      }
    });
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Check the closing bracket